# how to extract text from rolling credits video & save output in text file?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, ocr

video contains frames,& if we extracted each frame & apply ocr,it will giving same txt results, i want final output contains all credits.

i tried easyocr to extract txt ,i got text files contins txt, but almost all files are similar so my goal to get uniueq txt from rolling video

```
import cv2
import easyocr

# Initialize EasyOCR
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])

# Open the video file
video = cv2.VideoCapture('path/to/video')

# Define the confidence threshold
confidence_threshold = 0.65

# Define the text accumulator
text_accumulator = []

# Loop over all frames in the video
while True:
    # Read the next frame
    ret, frame = video.read()
    
    # Break if no more frames
    if not ret:
        break
    
    # Preprocess the frame (e.g. convert to grayscale, apply thresholding, etc.)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    
    # Extract text from the preprocessed frame
    results = reader.readtext(binary, detail=0, paragraph=True, text_threshold=0.50)
    
    # Check if the frame contains scrolling credits
    contains_credits = False
    for result in results:
        if result.endswith('-'):
            contains_credits = True
            break
    
    # If the frame contains scrolling credits, accumulate the text
    if contains_credits:
        text_accumulator.extend(results)
    
# Combine all the extracted text into a single text file
with open('output.txt', 'a') as f:
    for line in text_accumulator:
        f.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: Add each line from OCR to set before saving to a file ?

Comment: it will not work,set will save uniq char only